# Cannot find Meeting_id in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, endpoint, microsoft-live-meeting

I am trying to run the "Get All Recordings" endpoint call on Postman. [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/{meeting_id}/recordings](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/%7Bmeeting_id%7D/recordings)

The above call needs a `Meeting_id` which I cannot find from any other endpoint call or from Microsoft Teams UI.
I tried to create a meeting, get the response of it and using `meeting_id` from response but it gives me following error:

[image]

One of the `meeting_id` is what you get from meeting detail page on MS Teams but that is not acceptable

[image]

Is there a way we can get the meeting_id to run Get all Recordings call?

Comment: Can you please refer this thread once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597576/microsoft-graph-api-cannot-get-recordings-after-creating-meeting-using-onlinem.

Comment: If you have a meeting created via Teams UI, you can get meeting id by retrieving an online meeting by joinWebUrl/joinMeetingId. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKhfZ.png. Please refer these examples - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-retrieve-an-online-meeting-by-joinweburl, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-retrieve-an-online-meeting-by-joinmeetingid