# Microsoft Graph API - Cannot Get Recordings after creating meeting using onlineMeeting

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm getting error

```
No iCalUid found for the meeting. This API is supported only for calendar backed OnlineMeeting.
```

##### It is giving me response in manual process

> Schedule Meeting > Join > End > get the recordings using meetingid.

Manual-way works, because it is storing event in Calendar and has iCallUId.
If I create meeting using events API, Still I am getting error when called using
`onlineMeetings/{meeting-id}/recordings`

I am following **v1.0 of Graph API** not the beta.

Has anyone attempted this process, or am I missing the any flow.
I am testing this without SDK.
Even others are facing **iCallUId** problem.

I am trying to get the teams meeting recordings performed using onlineMeeting graph API via HTTP only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with meeting created using events API.

1. Create an event as online meeting using this example [Create and enable an event as an online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting)
2. Copy the joinUrl from the response [image: List item]
3. [Retrieve an online meeting using the joinWebUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-retrieve-an-online-meeting-by-joinweburl) from above step. [image]
4. Copy the id which is the meeting id and call the graph API to get the recordings. [image]

Comment: Thanks @meghana-msft
I tried this way, it works, but I wanted to know, is it possible to enable meeting automatically, onlineMeeting supported recordAutomatically but events API doesn't supports.

Comment: The Events endpoint does not allow auto recording of meetings.

Comment: I got another problem; the recordings endpoint doesn't provide recording duration.
I am trying to get the transcripts too.
I couldn't figure it out which transcript is related to which recordings.
Is there a way to identify the each transcript and recording association.

Currently I am loosely checking with createdtime and matching.

Comment: Currently the only way to check seems to be checking via createdDateTime.